# Can't create android onListItemClick method

Tags: java, android

Right now I'm trying to create an android onListItemClick method. But every time I do it get tons of syntax errors saying expected semicolon. Normally when I get syntax errors like that I know to just add a semi-colon but in this situation I have no clue how semi-colons are supposed to be applied to a thing like that. Is there even supposed to be semi colons in such a statement in the first place? Here is the code

```
package net.androidbootcamp.coffeefinder;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Menu Select Array
        String[] CoffeeShop = {"Creation","Starbucks","Caribou","Mo'Joe" };
        //Set list adapter for list
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.Coffee,CoffeeShop));
        //Create actions of list

        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go outside your onCreate:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Menu Select Array
        String[] CoffeeShop = {"Creation","Starbucks","Caribou","Mo'Joe" };
        //Set list adapter for list
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.Coffee,CoffeeShop));
        //Create actions of list
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {

    } 

}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have never used this method before. I did not mean to be such a newb

Comment: No worries. That's what this place is for. Hope it worked for you!

Comment: You can use this and the method should be outside the onCreate() as @dokkaebi said

Answer (score 0):

The method is something like this which should be in onCreate():

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              // selected item will be in position
              //do what ever you want to do.

          }
        });
```