# List View can't run

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I have written code about ListView in Android with Eclipse. I have followed tutorial based on book. But after i copied the code and run with Emulator. The Force Close message appeared. Like the image below:

[image: Force Close]

I don't know whats the probem occured. Instead, i have searched the solution in this question:
[Can't create android onListItemClick method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736168/cant-create-android-onlistitemclick-method)

And my code like the image below:
[image: Code]

The image below shown the logcat:
[image: Logcat]
Can you give me solutions?

Comment: Where is your logcat??Post it. `It play very important roll over here.`

Comment: Are you sure TextView and ListView is inside `R.layout.main` file?

Comment: show your logcat error please

Comment: Where you have `ListView` object, where you initialize it? where you set Adapter, and Listener?

Comment: @Emil You can refer all the comment one by one. One of the comment dam sure meting to your `NPE`.

Comment: @MD please check, i have update with the logcat

Comment: @Emil Ohhh It's match with `Der Golem` comment. second last..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#758AA7"
        android:padding="1px"
        android:text="Click : "
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
TextView content;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    String[] CoffeeShop = {"Creation","Starbucks","Caribou","Mo'Joe" };

    // Define a new Adapter
    // First parameter - Context
    // Second parameter - Layout for the row
    // Third - the Array of data

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CoffeeShop);

    // Assign adapter to List
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

// ListView Clicked item index
    int itemPosition = position;

    // ListView Clicked item value
    String itemValue = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

    content.setText("Click : \n  Position :" + itemPosition
            + "  \n  ListItem : " + itemValue);

    }
}
```

Comment: please explain why for better understanding, OP only learns with explanation....

Comment: please check i have updated answer.it's working perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer my mistake in .xml file on initialize ListView. Based on @Der Golem said in the comment of this question

Comment: yes you have done mistake on declaring listview id in xml.

Comment: hey @Emil i was sent you answer first.so you have to accept my answer first.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your ListView is named `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"`.

Since you are using a `ListActivity` (the same goes for `ListFragments`), this is **the only possible name** for your ListView.